# Where do I get the structure for FILE in linux

Tags: file

I want to look at the definition of FILE. FILE * we use in file handling, but I want to look at the structure and would like to know its fields.

Comment: it's an abstraction. you don't need to know what's inside. that is, unless you work on the kernel...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: `FILE` is user-space, right?  It's the stuff underlying *file descriptors* that would be relevant at the kernel level.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Is it libc? then that...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Yup, libc is where stuff like `fopen` is implemented, ultimately in terms of sys-calls.

Answer (score 0):

file struct can be different depending on your implementation. You can take a look in your implementation under `/usr/include/stdio.h`